# why my image won't get remove when it intersects with another image

Tags: animation, javafx, imageview, intersection

I made 2 imageviews, one which I move using arrow keys and one that moves using transition animation.I created a class and created a method that takes as parameters those 2 images and the pane which they are added in.I  made 2 bound that get the images boundInParent and also a boolean variable which has as value boun1 intersecting bound2.I made an if statement that if the  boolean variable is true, then I would remove one image from the pane.

```
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Score {
    public static void scoreUpdate(ImageView spaceship, ImageView coin, AnchorPane gamePane){
        Bounds bound1=spaceship.getBoundsInParent();
        Bounds bound2= coin.getBoundsInParent();

        boolean intersecting= bound1.intersects(bound2);
        if(intersecting){
            gamePane.getChildren().remove(coin);
            

        }
    }
}
```

I just tried putting the code in the main class, but that didn't work. Chatgpt  doesn't help either. Well, I hope I find an answer here.